# Multiple Schemes in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, google-plus

I'm currently creating an app and I have a debug scheme and just recently created a release one base off the debug scheme. I'm getting this weird thing happening, where I've used pods to include google plus framework, but for some reason in the release scheme this:

```
GPPSignIn *signIn = [GPPSignIn sharedInstance];
```

always returns nil but in debug works absolutely fine. has anyone else experienced behaviour like this before? I'm using multiple libraries in pods which all work perfectly find in release but google plus is being a pain. Any help with this would be awesome

Comment: You're not talking about schemes, You're talking about build configurations

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution afterwards. it was a difference in compiler settings between the two schemes. Setting them both to none made it work perfectly.